# Bootstrap Tour Navigation issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i try to implement bootstrap tour to my site using  [this example](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/oqw1uDAAi7yLjp7gtjFJ/)
i'ts easy.. but i face problem when script follows the patch to second page, because i have non standard links.....like

```
path: "/index.php?page=orders",
```

but if i use standard link

```
 path: "/NextPage.php",
```

everything works fine.

When i click  "Next button" tour menu dissapears and nothing happens. If i follow link  `/index.php?page=orders`  manually, tour continues as it should be.

Seems that bootstrap tour cannot follow my link and can't change patch..
any ideas how to fix it?

```
$(function() {
  // define tour
  var tour = new Tour({
       basePath: location.pathname.slice(1, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')),
      steps: [
  {
    path: "/index.php?page=index", 
     element: "#showtransit",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  },
  {
     path: "/index.php?page=orders", 
    element: "#Show_orders_types",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step"
  }
],
    backdrop: true,
  });
  // init tour
  tour.init();
  // start tour
  $('#start-tour').click(function() {
    tour.restart();
  });
});
```

also did not work

```
  {
    element: "#Show_orders_types",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step",
    redirect: function(){ document.location.href = 'index.php?&page=orders';}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is OnNext: event. + JS

```
  {

    element: "#showtransit",
    title: "Title of my step",
    content: "Content of my step",
    onNext: function(){ document.location.href = 'index.php?&page=orders';}
    },
```